# How to return the first result in an ArrayList using iterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

I am working on a robot maze where the robot finds the target without bumping into walls. As a "backtrack" method, I need the robot to go in the opposite direction as it did when it first came across a junction. This is my code:

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your robot needs to "remember" being at a particular junction (x,y), right? I presume this is because when you randomly choose one of the multiple paths available, you don't want to choose a path you already chose before. Please correct me if I am misunderstanding this.

Comment: @ChthonicProject that is correct. I have "remembered" all the junctions it comes across by storing them in an arraylist. However, when it has been down all the paths, it needs to go down the path it first came from. Does that make sense?

Comment: FYI: This is a classical problem out of the book "When to use recursion" and can be solved much more elegantly by using recursion. It's just that in order to understand recursion you first need to understand recursion. ;)

Comment: Ah, I see. But in that case, shouldn't `get(0)` on the `ArrayList<Junction>` give you what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I think you may have forgot to continue iterating through the list after you did the initial `Junction currentJunction = junctionIterator.next();`, so you never really moved through the list. Also, you may want to always check `hasNext()` before using `next()` in case there is an empty list.

```
public int searchJunction(IRobot robot) {

    boolean foundJunction = false;

    Junction currentJunction = null;

    //Iterate through list until the end, or until correct junction is found.
    while (!foundJunction && junctionIterator.hasNext()) {
        currentJunction = junctionIterator.next();
        if ((((currentJunction.x)==(robot.getLocation().x))) && ((currentJunction.y)==(robot.getLocation().y))) {
            foundJunction = true;
        }
    }

    return currentJunction;
}
```

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: well regards to there being an empty list, that will never be the case because this method will only be executed if it has come across this junction before. Secondly, I don't think I explained my problem properly. Sometimes, the robot would have come across the junction several times. I need to find the arrived heading from the first time it came across it.

Comment: So if the robot has already been to a junction once, should it not add a new junction? Your code now seems to add a new junction each time, even if you have been there already. In that case, my answer will work. Feel free to explain further if I am interpreting your problem wrong still.

Comment: The specification was that it should add a new Junction each time. I just need to be able to return the first time it came across it.

Comment: Thats what I thought. In that case, the code segment I provided will work. If you are looking for the first time it ran across that junction, it will return the first junction that matches the current location in the list.

Comment: I tried compiling it but it required currentJunction to be initialised

Comment: Sorry, had to edit so that 'junction' in the if statement was 'currentJunction'. Also assigned 'currentJunction' to null.

Comment: Okay so I used your code but now, whenever its backtracking and reaches a junction it has already met, this comes up and it freezes `Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
 at RobotData.searchJunction(Explorer.java:248)
 at RobotData.reverseHeading(Explorer.java:261)
 at Explorer.backtrack(Explorer.java:74)
 at Explorer.junction(Explorer.java:122)
 at Explorer.controlRobot(Explorer.java:56)
 ... 5 more`

Answer (score 0):

inside the while loop you're having trouble with you don't seem to be going through to the last junction... Is this by design? Or should it be

```
    while (junctionIterator.hasNext()) {
    if ((((currentJunction.x)==(robot.getLocation().x))) && ((currentJunction.y)==(robot.getLocation().y))) 
        break;
    currentJunction = junctionIterator.next();
}
```

Let me know if this helps or if I misunderstood what you're asking

Comment: I don't think I explained my problem properly. Sometimes, the robot would have come across the junction several times. I need to find the arrived heading from the first time it came across it.